# Global and GWR models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spatial, spatial-correlation

I have mortality data for municipalities in my country and I would like to know if an approach such as modelling with a Linear Regression and if the assumptions like normality, equal variance and more specially, the spatial independence of residuals are not met, I should try a global model like Spatial Lag or Spatial Error, test for spatial independence and then use a GWR (Geographically Weighted Regression) and compare which of these models is the best with AIC for example. Does this approach make sense?